# Python: maintain key sort order on dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to iteratively add elements to a dictionary with an integer key for which I would like to keep a key-ordering. Modern Python (3.7+) keeps an insertion order on `dict`, but I need a **key** ordering.

Example use-case:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(10):
    idx = i + np.random.randint(10)
    my_dict[idx].append(i)

    # Do something with my_dict
    ...

print(my_dict)
```

Example output:

```
>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {9: [0, 4, 9], 10: [1], 2: [2], 6: [3, 5], 7: [6, 7], 16: [8]})
```

Desired output:

```py
print(defaultdict(list, sorted(my_dict.items())))
>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [2], 6: [3, 5], 7: [6, 7], 9: [0, 4, 9], 10: [1], 16: [8]})
```

Of course, this is a very simple sort, but the index shifts (computed above as `i + np.random.randint(10)`) can become arbitrarily large and I need a low time-complexity solution. Also note that I am also removing items from `my_dict` inside the loop (e.g., keys with value lesser or equal to `i`).

What kind of objects/ data structures does Python provide to achieve this? I've looked at PriorityQueue (heapq), which preserves the ordering I need but only that. I need the `get` and `pop` methods from the conventional dictionary + the ordering of e.g., PriorityQueue on the keys without having to expensively sort at every iteration.

**Edit**: The best current solution that I was able to find is the use of SortedDict from the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html#) library. Unfortunately, this solution loses the `O(1)` time complexity of `dict.pop`, to `O(log N)`, but the dictionary is kept in key-order with `O(log N)` instead of `O(N log N)`.

I am still open to hearing alternative solutions that preserves the characteristics of `SortedDict`, but provides `O(1)` time complexity for `SortedDict.pop`. Note that `pop` is always called on the smallest key, just like a queue (/ dequeue).

Comment: You might want to put your keys separately in a sorted list. Use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for insertion & search.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about `bisect', thanks a lot! I read that insort is O(N) in time-complexity. Is this the best possible? Or does there also exist a log(N) solution or better?

Comment: For O(logN) insertion you'll need to write a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Thanks again, the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html) library does exactly what I want with `SortedDict`. Which is I believe based on bisect.insort, but in a more clever way. It's probably the fastest solution possible to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I made to sort the dictionary keys.

```py
def dict_sort(d):
  return({x:d[x] for x in sorted(d)})
```

Basically, the function iterates through the `sorted()` version of the keys, and then maps them to a new dictionary (in order) and returns that new dictionary.

Call like this:

```py
a=dict_sort(my_dict)
print(a) #this prints out sorted dictionary
```

Hope this was a help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm specifically asking for a datastructure that would require me to **not** sort. This easy solution is `O(N * log N)`. I need something with at most `O(log N)` for a `push` operation, and preferably `O(1)` for a `pop` operation. E.g., a heapQ key-list is the closest I can get with `O(log N)` time complexity for `pop`.